# Transformer with DC

Tags: transformer, dc

As far as I understand, when we pass DC current through a transformer, nothing should happen in the secondary coil. This is because

> transformers operate on the principle that current in a wire generates
>   a magnetic field. And more importantly that a change in magnetic flux
>   creates a current in a wire within that field

However, this simulation shows something completely different:

[image: transformer DC simulation]

[Link to the simulation](http://www.falstad.com/circuit/circuitjs.html?cct=$%201%200.000005%2010.20027730826997%2050%205%2042%0Av%20176%20272%20176%20144%200%200%2060%2010%200%200%200.5%0Aw%20352%20224%20352%20272%200%0AT%20272%20192%20352%20192%200%2010%201%200.038963799025718136%20-0.020335221263162243%200.999%0Aw%20272%20192%20272%20144%200%0Aw%20272%20224%20272%20272%200%0Ar%20272%20144%20176%20144%200%20100%0Aw%20176%20272%20272%20272%200%0Aw%20352%20272%20448%20272%200%0Aw%20352%20144%20448%20144%200%0Ar%20448%20144%20448%20272%200%20300%0Aw%20352%20192%20352%20144%200%0Ao%200%2064%200%204099%2010%200.1%200%202%200%203%0Ao%209%2064%200%204099%2010%200.025%201%202%209%203%0A)

Can someone please explain me what is going on here?

Comment: Last transformer I designed works just fine at DC. It depends what your model is supposed to represent in reality.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The key here is the concept of DC being in a *steady state*. That is, if the DC was turned on at the moment of the Big Bang and remained exactly the same until the Big Crunch or Big Nothingness, depending on which theory you put faith in, then there will be zero current in the secondary.

However that is not the case. The DC will have been turned on at some point, and will turn off again at some other point. That change of voltage (and current) in the primary causes a change in magnetic flux, which causes current to be induced in the secondary.

Turn the DC on and off at 50 or 60 times per second and you have an AC signal at (fundamentally) the mains frequency.

The Falstad animation always starts with everything at 0, and so the DC source is then an immediate change in the voltage (and current) which starts the whole induction thing going. Eventually the fluxes will even out (the time being defined by the resistance and inductance of the components in the circuit) and no further current will be induced in the secondary.

You can try it yourself. If you get a normal mains-to-9V transformer (for instance) stripped of all other components (no rectifiers, etc), and connect a small neon indicator light to the high voltage side, then get an AA battery (or similar) and connect it across the low voltage side. The neon will flash briefly. Disconnect the battery and it will flash again briefly. Just like the Falstad animation.

Answer (score 2):

> However, this simulation shows something completely different

Remarkably for this crappy toy, no it doesn't. If you'd have waited until the falsetad cartoon finished (got past a second or so in the time line it uses) you might get your answer i.e. current diminishes to zero.

At start up there are the expected transients because you are applying a 10 volt signal to the primary. Something will get through to the secondary but this fades.